# Deeplearning4j : How do I know if I have INTEL compilers installed on my windows machine?

Tags: java

I'm learning Deeplearning4j, but don't know how to start, got stuck in the 1st step.

On it's page : http://deeplearning4j.org/gettingstarted.html it says "Due to our reliance on Jblas for CPUs, native bindings for Blas are required."

And for windows : "See http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/"

So I went to the site, and then I got stuck.

I'm a Java developer, but it says "Fortran", "Visual Studio" ... this and that, I don't know what to do.

And it says "If you have INTEL compilers installed on your machine" do this, if not do that, how do I know if I have INTEL compilers installed on my windows machine ?

It has a guide  : "Running LAPACK under Windows"

But I don't know if the steps "Part 1-a", "Part 1-b" ... are necessary or optional, very confusing.

I wish it is as easy as downloading a jar file and start using it, but it's more complicated than that, so I wonder if there is any Java programmer here that has used Deeplearning4j, and can tell me the steps I need to take to get started on 64-bit Intel running Windows 7 ?

Answer (score 1):

Got the following answer from Chris Nicholson :

Hi Frank -

We're looking forward to the day when we can offer an easy install for Windows users.

For the moment, you'll need to go to Lapack to get BLAS running.

Lapack will ask you if you have Intel compilers. You don't.

Instead, you will need to install MinGW 32 bits (the download button is on the upper right; BLAS does not play nice with 64 bit) and then download the Prebuilt dynamic libraries using Mingw. Lapack offers the alternative of VS Studio Solution.

You'll also want to look at the documentation for Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms (BLAS).